# Why is this statement about $\text{Span}$ false?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, span

Here is a true-false question known to be **false**:

If $\mathbf{a}$ is in $\text{Span} \left \{ \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c} \right \}$, then $\mathbf{b}$ is in $\text{Span}\left\{\mathbf{a},\mathbf{c}\right\}$.

Why is it false? Have I forgotten to consider some edge cases?

Comment: Let $\mathbf a=\mathbf c$ and figure out the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbf{a}$ may be a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{c}$, and independent of $\mathbf{b}$.